# How to read and manipulate a Json file with Apache beam in Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a .txt file which has the JSON format. I want to read, manipulate and restructure the file (change the fields name...) 
How Can I do this in Python with Apache Beam?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To be able to read a Json File with Apache Beam on Python, you can make a Custom Coder:

CF : https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#specifying-coders

```
class JsonCoder(object):
"""A JSON coder interpreting each line as a JSON string."""

def encode(self, x):
    return json.dumps(x)

def decode(self, x):
    return json.loads(x)
```

And then you have to specify it when you read or write your data, for instance :

```
lines = p | 'read_data' >> ReadFromText(known_args.input, coder=JsonCoder())
```

Best regards, work well ;)

Answer (score -1):

Let's consider that you have a sample data like this:

```
{
    "magic": "atMSG",
    "type": "DT",
    "headers": null,
    "messageschemaid": null,
    "messageschema": null,
    "message": {
        "data": {
            "Column_Name_1": "data_in_quotes",
            "Column_Name_2": "data_in_quotes",
            "Column_Name_n": "data_in_quotes"
        },
        "beforeData": null,
        "headers": {
            "operation": "INSERT",
            "changeSequence": "20200822230048000000000017887787417",
            "timestamp": "2020-08-22T23:00:48.000",
            "streamPosition": "00003EB9_0000000000000006_00000F4D9C6F8AFF01000001000CD387000C00580188000100000F4D9C333900",
            "transactionId": "some_id"
        }
    }
}
```

and you want to read data only from:
"message":{"data":{"Column_Name_1":"data_in_quotes", "Column_Name_2":"data_in_quotes", "Column_Name_n":"data_in_quotes"}

I used the following code to read this type of NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON and write to bigquery:

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.io import ReadFromText
from apache_beam.io import WriteToText
import json  
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

class Printer(beam.DoFn):
 def process(self,data_item):
    print (data_item)
def printer(data_item):
    print (data_item)
    
class custom_json_parser(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        norm = json_normalize(element, max_level=1)
        l = norm["message.data"].to_list()
        return l
table_schema = 'Column_name_1:Data_Type,Column_name_2:Data_Type,Column_name_n:Data_Type'

options = PipelineOptions()
p = beam.Pipeline(options=options)

projectId='your_project_id'
datasetId='Landing'

data_from_source = (p
                    | "READ FROM JSON" >> ReadFromText("gs://bucket/folder/file_name_having json data")
                    | "PARSE JSON" >> beam.Map(json.loads)
                    | "CUSTOM JOSN PARSE" >> beam.ParDo(custom_json_parser())
                    #| "PRINT DATA" >> beam.ParDo(Printer()) <- uncomment this line to see data onto GCP Dataflow Notebooks Console
                    #| WriteToText( "gs://ti-project-1/output/",".txt") <- to write it to text file
                    |"WriteToBigQuery" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                        "{0}:{1}.table_name".format(projectId, datasetId),
                        schema=table_schema,
                    #    write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                        write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,
                        create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED
                    )
)

result = p.run()
```

The above code will do the following things:

1. Read and parse the JSON file
2. Create the table in GCP BigQuery
3. Load the data into the table in TRUNCATE mode. For Append, comment WRITE_TRUNCATE and uncomment WRITE_APPEND